# our country is hurting right now

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "our country is hurting right now" mean "our country is feeling pain right now"?

> Janet Yellen (American economist) tweeted:
> this week— **our country is hurting right now**, but we know what we need to do to help. We need the American Rescue Plan so Americans make it through the pandemic and are met with a strong, growing economy on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does "our country is hurting right now" mean "our country is feeling
> pain right now"?

Yes.  However, a country cannot feel pain or hurt because it is an abstraction.  Yellen used "our country" figuratively.  Her meaning was "All of the people in our country are hurting right now."